# How to put a multi line equation inside a box

Tags: equations

I have a multi-line equation;

```
\begin{align} 
  \label{eq:er25} 
  F(\gamma) &= aaaaa \nonumber\\ 
  &+ bbbbbb \nonumber\\ 
  &- cccccc 
\end{align}
```

How I can put this equation inside a box?

Comment: With the package `bm` you can create a box with the environment `empheq` wirth something like `\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox] equation \end{empheq}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some some details of what can be done with `empheq` and `mathtools`(which is loaded by empeheq). The `overload` option simplifies the syntax, but has the drawback that breaking equations over pages is forbidden (however you can use the `AmSalign` & the like,. environments to enable the ordinary behaviour). The `\Aboxed` command allows boxing a line with one alignment point.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\colorlet{textcolor}{black}

\newcommand*{\widebox}[2][0.5em]{\fbox{\hspace{#1}$\displaystyle #2$\hspace{#1}}}
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@Aboxed}{%
\boxed {#1#2}}
{%
\color{HotPink3}\boxed {\color{textcolor}#1#2}}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}[box=\widebox]
  \label{eq:er25}
  F(γ) &= aaaaa \notag\\
  &+ bbbbbb \notag\\
  &- cccccc
\end{align}

\fboxrule=1pt%
\begin{empheq}[box=\fcolorbox{HotPink3}{MistyRose2!30! white}]{alignat = 2}
 \label{eq:er25}
\Aboxed{F(γ) = & aaaaa }& \Aboxed{G & = dddddd}\notag\\
 &\! + bbbbbb \notag\\
 & - cccccc
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]